# Binding certain function keys (FN) to AwesomeWM breaks them until unbound

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, awesome

Using a [Dell Inspiron 15 7580](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-7000-laptop/spd/inspiron-15-7580-laptop). Awesome is version 4.3

I check the name of my keys using `xev`. Pressing my volume keys return the usual results.

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x1200002, time 13968342, (38,56), root:(841,97),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x169, subw 0x1200002, time 13968484, (38,56), root:(841,97),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So I bind the key to AwesomeWM...

```lua
awful.key({ }, "XF86AudioLowerVolume", 
    awful.spawn("amixer set Master 5%-"), {})
```

But once I refresh Awesome, the binding doesn't work AND `xev` returns a different result

```
FocusOut event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  105 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

The function keys work again once I unbind them. But why is this occurring? It's not even my volume key once I bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For some reason, I had to use `awful.spawn` inside an anonymous function. I'd figured since `awful.spawn` was a function, I didn't have to do this. But you do, unfortunately.

```lua
awful.key({ }, "XF86AudioLowerVolume", function() 
    awful.spawn("amixer set Master 5%-") 
end, 
{description = "lower audio", group = "audio"}),
```

**EDIT** Figured I'd explain it.

So the `press` argument to `key.new` (`__call` metatable for `awful.key`) requires a `function` as an argument. `awful.spawn` *is* of type `function`, but what's returned by it *isn't* a function. So for times like these, one can only pass a function as an argument, rather than calling the function.

**Good example**

```lua
-- Notice I passed awful.spawn without calling it
awful.key({ }, "t", awful.spawn, {})
```

**Bad example**

```lua
-- awful.spawn is called here, so whats returned by it is passed as an argument
awful.key({ }, "t", awful.spawn(), {})
```

Remember that you can always check your types in lua by calling `type`.

```lua
type(awful.spawn)
function
```

Comment: Good job figuring it out! This is because Awesome knows how to call a function as a callback, but has no way of knowing what arguments to send to that function at the time of the event. Same goes for other languages/frameworks with callbacks.